# 3D rotation while object being translated

Tags: android

I've been playing with Android animation framework and I found the following 3D rotation sample code:

http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/animation/Transition3d.html

http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/animation/Rotate3dAnimation.html

It does pretty much what I want but I want the ImageView to rotate while it's being translated from point A to point B and the it should rotate along it's own center(which is moving) instead of the center of the container of screen.

Does anyone know how to do that?

-Rachel

Answer (score 0):

Well it's pretty close to what you posted.  Essentially you're multiplying the rotational matrix by the translation matrix.  That's essentially what happens under the covers.  Android hides that detail from you with it's API:

```
Matrix matrix = transformation.getMatrix();
matrix.rotate( rotateX, rotateY );
matrix.postTranslate( transX, transY );
```

Rotate first then translate will rotate the image around it's own axis first before translating it.

Comment: Did you mean matrix.setRotate(rotateX, rotateY)? I think this is for 2D rotation tho. Don't we have to use camera.rotateY to achieve 3D rotation effect?